# BizTalk throws a NullReferenceException between the receiving adapter and pipeline

Tags: .net, biztalk, nullreferenceexception, biztalk-2009

I've developed a BizTalk pipeline and it while it works fine on the development VM, it does not in the production environment. Both environments run BizTalk Server 2009.

All the components in my pipeline work fine on other pipelines. The Exception I get is this, in the Windows Application Event Log (everything between `<` and `>` is irrelevant):

> A message received by adapter "FILE" on receive location <Receive Location> with URI <URI> is suspended. 
>    Error details: There was a failure executing the receive pipeline: <My Pipeline> Source: "Unknown " Receive Port: <Receive Port> URI: <URI>  Reason: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
>    MessageId:  <Message ID> 
>    InstanceID: <Instance ID>

I know that **no components** are executed because the first component writes something to the database of a custom tracking application. This does not happen on this pipeline, and the same component works fine for all other pipelines that use it.

All the components on my pipeline are also used in other pipelines, none of which give this kind of problem.

So really this exception is happening **between** the adapter and the pipeline. Originally, the adapter used is a `WCF-Custom` with `sqlBinding`, but using a `File` adapter results in the same exception.

Now, the Event Log entry is the **only trace** I have for all messages that go through this pipeline. There are no suspended instances. When I use the default PassThrough or XMLReceive pipelines, it just works.

Where do I go from here? What can be wrong?
Is there a way to get some sort of stacktrace for this exception to help track it down?

Comment: If you use the PassThrough pipeline, does a message hit the MessageBox?  Does the component do any work on the Stream directly?

Comment: @boatseller I've tried using the XMLReceive pipeline, it works that way. The components do operations on the stream indeed, but like I said this does not give problems in other pipelines with which the components are shared.

Comment: Can you ensure all the required Dlls by your custom pipeline are gac'd.  I ran into a similar problem with maps.

Comment: @Bitmask The pipeline assembly itself is definitely gac'd. The custom components don't have to be afaik, as it works fine for other pipelines. Besides, if that was the problem, the error would be more specific about not being able to load an assembly (had that on previous occasions). Anyway thanks for your thoughts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Out of desperation, I started deploying the pipeline over and over again, leaving off different components each time until I tracked down the culprit.

As it turns out, my local development VM (and Visual Studio) pulled one of the components out of the GAC rather than the standard `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft BizTalk Server 2009\Pipeline Components` folder. This assembly did not match the component on the production environment.

Comment: No!  Wait! Stop! ;)  All Custom Pipeline Components should be in the GAC only, *not the Pipeline Components folder*.  The Pipeline Components folder is a compatibility vestige from BizTalk Server 2004 and should not be used.  GAC support was introduced in BizTalk Server 2006 so Pipeline Components should be GAD'd along with all other BizTalk Assemblies.

Comment: @boatseller I'm afraid I will never convince my colleagues to convert now, I bet they didn't know that (and I've learnt everything from them). The legacy method still works so we can't risk switching over. I know it **will** give trouble. But thanks for letting me now, I'll definitely remember!

Comment: @boatseller Microsoft says otherwise here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa577482.aspx "All the .NET pipeline component assemblies (native and custom) must be located in the <installation directory>\Pipeline Components folder to be executed by the server. You do not need to add a custom pipeline component to be used by the BizTalk Runtime to the Global Assembly Cache (GAC)."

Comment: There was/is also a gotcha (http://geekswithblogs.net/sthomas/archive/2006/09/27/92513.aspx) that you had to have it in the pipelines component folder before you GAC it in your dev environment.  However if you are using the BizTalk Deployment Framework you probably do want to GAC them.  It has been a long running debate :-)

Comment: @Dijkgraaf it seems I've done more or less the opposite of what happened in the blogpost you linked to. I had it GAC'ed on the dev machine but not in the production environment. When swapping references in my VM, I could not open my pipeline at all and that's where the null reference emerged: it happened when trying to read the `PropertyBag` on the rogue component. I had to open it with the xml editor and remove all usages of the component, and re-add them with the proper reference set.

Comment: So the moral of the story is if you want it GACed copy/deploy it to the Pipeline Component folder and then GAC it from there.

Comment: @Dijkgraaf seems pretty much it. Thanks for your input.

Comment: That documentation is incorrect. As a qualification, I have filed at least 4 other doc bugs for BizTalk and when/if Connect is back, I will file this one. It's quite simple, there's nothing special about a Pipeline Component Assembly so it belongs in the GAC *with all other BizTalk Assemblies*. As for SWT's blog, again, there is nothing special going on here, resolving to the GAC is the expected behavior of Visual Studio. You can add the reference directly from the GAC or *any other folder* such as your project output folder. There is not need to put anything in the Pipeline Components folder.